# Is there any pre and post snapshot hooks for apt in ubuntu for btrfs snapper, like in arch, fedora and opensuse?

Tags: apt, btrfs, snapshot

Is there any pre and post snapshot hooks for apt in ubuntu for btrfs snapper, like in arch, fedora and opensuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I installed snapper-gui and I found that snapshots were already being createed after every apt transaction!
Usually, in other distros I had to install some package-manager hooks for this to work.
I think this was automatically installed as a dependency in Ubuntu